# converting mysql datebase

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a question about converting mysql databases, I doing now new site, and want to use my old database, which is in latin_swedish_1 colacolation I want to convert this old database into utf8_general_ci, how can I do this? can anybody help? thank you/..

Answer (score 0):

Check This answer:
change database, table and column collation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/change-database-collation

Comment: I have tried this but I get onknown characters in my database/ any ideas?

Comment: How many tables you have in your database? 
Maybe you can just create new database schema using UTF-8 and use - `SELECT INTO TABLE` to move and convert it to new database.